# How to install Google Services on a Garmin Fleet 790 Navigation Tablet?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I tried different approaches.

Installing the APKs: Login, Framework, Service and last but not at least Playstore wont work. (I tried it successfully on fire tablet)

In factory mode the menu Point: install from Sd Card wont be Displayed. To install Gapps from there.

Is there any other method to make Google Play Services run on the device?

the navigation tablet is  based on Android 6.0.1

i tried to follow the describtion from @izzy, but if I use the adb sideload i get:

> "adb : sideload connection: closed .. trying pre kitkat sideload
>   method..'

and than the connection fails again and is closed too.   starting the device in factory mode and try to install it says:

> "failed to open driver control no such file"

underwards it says that i could use adb sideload, but when i try my computer says

> "no connected device"

Comment: Please see: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](/q/27808/16575) – this includes GServices. Best approach is OpenGApps (mentioned in an answer there). And you can probably use `adb sideload` if "install from SD card" isn't available.

Comment: @Izzy thanks. i tried to follow the describtion, but if I use the adb sideload i get: "adb : sideload connection: closed .. trying pre kitkat sideload method and there connection fails again and is closed'
starting the device in factory mode and try to install it says: "failed to open driver control no such file"

Comment: OK, that seem to be device-specific issues. I'll reopen this question so you get a chance to solve those. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy thank you